# Should a playlist be deleted after deleting it's videos?

Tags: deletion, content-management

User can upload videos and create playlists with that videos. What would happen if the user deleted videos used in a playlist? Should a playlist be also deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should the system delete an empty playlist?

**No.** Because I've just removed the content (songs, videos, photos etc.) from that playlist or folder. I might want to add new videos to the same playlist later in future. **But, a system should give an option to delete the playlist if user wants to**.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to [@Dipak's answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/104982/32130).

Lets say a user has a playlist with 3 elements. The user deletes element 1. After he deletes element 2. When he deletes element 3, he might not realize the playlist will end up "empty". So when the user deletes the last element you could:

- inform him that the list will be empty
- ask if he also wants to delete the list

Otherwise the user will wonder why the list isn't showing where it should.
An empty list might need to have a different display than a filled one.

Answer (score 0):

I also believe that it shouldn't delete the playlist.

Making the analogy of a playlist as a "folder": the same situation if you create a folder on Gmail and it doesn't have any email inside; the folder continues to exist. The same if you have a folder on your OS and took all the files from it. The folder is still there.